# Добавить файл в определенную папку репозитория

Tags: git, github

есть репозиторий в котором папка test http://prntscr.com/rv7uhp и мне надо именно в нее добавить файл, как это сделать?

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, поясните почему простой комит файла не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git clone https://github.com/Alexkov23/global.git
cd global/test
```

Далее добавляем файл в эту папку

```
git add -A
git commit
git push
```

Если нужно сделать это через веб-интерфейс, то при создании в начале имени файла можно прописать "test/" или перейти в папку и нажать на "Upload" или "Create"